# How to split file in two by segments of 4 lines in unix

Tags: unix, awk, split

I'm searching for a way how to split my file in two, haven't found an answer here. I have a large file (with millions of lines) and would like to split it in two files, always by four lines, i.e. the first four lines (1,2,3,4) go in the first output file, the second four lines (5,6,7,8) go in the second output file, then the third four lines (9,10,11,12) go again to the first output file, etc. I'm sure there will be a way - possibly using awk (?) but I can't get it right... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually the result should be 2 files if you follow the steps described.

Comment: @marcel: ah, right, misread the question.

Answer (score 3):

All you need is

```
awk 'NR%4==1{c=!c} {print > ("out"c)}'
```

Look:

```
$ seq 10 | awk 'NR%4==1{c=!c} {print $0 " > " ("out"c)}'
1 > out1
2 > out1
3 > out1
4 > out1
5 > out0
6 > out0
7 > out0
8 > out0
9 > out1
10 > out1
```

Answer (score 1):

another `awk`

```
awk '{print > "out_"((NR-1)%8>3)}' file
```

Comment: That will only work in some awks since an unparenthesized expression on the right side of output redirection is undefined behavior. But you know that....